# Is possible Get list of JSON objects with Spring RestTemplate but without ParameterizedTypeReference?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-rest

For `Spring Boot` **3.1.1**  - based on `Spring Framework` **6** - using the `RestTemplate` class, the following is valid:

```java
public ResponseEntity<Ciencia> findById(Integer id) {
    return restTemplate.getForEntity("/ciencias/uri/v1/ciencias/{id}",
                                     Ciencia.class,
                                     id);
}

public ResponseEntity<Collection<Ciencia>> findAll() {
    return restTemplate.exchange("/ciencias/uri/v1/ciencias",
                                 HttpMethod.GET,
                                 null,
                                 new ParameterizedTypeReference<Collection<Ciencia>>() {
    });
}
```

**Observation**

- Both return the `ResponseEntity<T>` type.

Therefore with this return type is possible retrieve the:

- Headers
- Status
- Body

Other approach is get the Body directly, therefore for the first method, it can be re-written as:

```
public Ciencia findById(Integer id) {
    return restTemplate.getForObject("/ciencias/uri/v1/ciencias/{id}",
                                     Ciencia.class,
                                     id);
}
```

It works fine.

**For *Academic* Purposes**

The second method, was re-written as follows

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<Ciencia> findAll() {
    return restTemplate.getForObject("/ciencias/uri/v1/ciencias",
                                     Collection.class);
}
```

**Observation**

- For this scenario, the `exchange` method was changed by `gerForObject`

but it throws:

```
Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.manuel.jordan.SpringBootWebRestClientApplication.main(SpringBootWebRestClientApplication.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.manuel.jordan.domain.Ciencia (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.manuel.jordan.domain.Ciencia is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at com.manuel.jordan.SpringBootWebRestClientApplication.lambda$reportxx$3(SpringBootWebRestClientApplication.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

**Question**

- Is possible Get list of JSON objects with Spring `RestTemplate` but without `ParameterizedTypeReference`?

**Notes**

- Yes, I know that `WebClient` replaces `RestTemplate`
- I am assuming that a *final/latest* improvement was applied to the `RestTemplate` class in the Spring Framework **5**.x series to offer an approach without using the `exchange` method and the `ParameterizedTypeReference` type

Comment: No it isn't it exists because of this. It needs the type information to determine the collection it needs to return and the type within the collection.